# Program linux command with pipe in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, command, pipe

I´m trying to execute the next linux command

```
 cat file_a file_b file_c | wc –l > result.txt
```

in a C program, but I´m not able to do it properly. I have very low level of C programming, and I would like to see how to make that command works in a C program.

This is the code I developed without success:

```
void main() {

execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat file1 file2 fileN | wc –l > lines.txt", 0);

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You probably get : `wc: –l: No such file or directory` and that is because you have probably copy pasted the shell command and you'r `-l` does not in fact have a dash, but some other character that reassembles it. The C code itself is correct.

Comment: @Alpar: well-spotted — that's a U+2013 EN DASH rather than U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS.

Answer (score 3):

I follow your example. 
Its results:

*implicit declaration of function 'execlp' is invalid in C99*

And some other warning errors.

But I think it would be better if you use the `system()` C-function, here is what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   system("cat filea fileb filec | wc -l > result.txt");

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After compilation that works!

If you want to run just a command without needing to read the resulting output, you could use the C-function `system()`, but if you want to run it getting its results, you should use `popen()`.

- [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system)
- [`popen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)